# How can I move kubernetes ephemeral storage to a different disk?

Tags: kubernetes, disk-volume, teamcity

I'm trying to run dynamic 'cloud' Teamcity Agents containers on an in-house server under K3s, prior to moving to a 'real' k18s installation, but my agents need 21G of ephemeral storage and kubernetes gets upset if I configure them to need more than 20G. My root partition is 20G total (12G available), so I'd prefer ephemeral storage to be backed by /local/k3s which is a bit bigger.

The closest I've found to 'configuring' this is
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage which says:

> Note: The kubelet will only track the root filesystem for ephemeral storage. OS layouts that mount a separate disk to /var/lib/kubelet or /var/lib/containers will not report ephemeral storage correctly.

So even if I make those soft links or bind-mounts or something, it seems I'm still stuck to the root partition size!

- Is there actually no way to move ephemeral volume storage? Amazon seems to allow lots of gigabytes for ephemeral storage.
- Assuming I'm doing something stupid in even trying this, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

PersistentVolumes(PV) and PersistentVolumeClaims(PVC) come handy in this scenario, you just need to follow three simple steps for achieving this.

- Attach the mount point to your node on which you need to have extra
  space(in your case it’s a single node).
- Create a persistent volume and persistent volume claim in kubernetes.
- Define the PVC in your deployment manifest file and your pods will be
  using this volume for storage.

Follow this [***official tutorial***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) for more information and detailed instructions related to configuration, also go through this [***k3s storage docs***](https://docs.k3s.io/storage) for more information.

Comment: @Timbaverstock is your issue resolved..? ping here if you need any additional help...

Comment: @KranthiveerDontinenti many thanks for this. We've suspended this for now, but I'll add the link to the ticket for when we pick it up again.